# Ways to measure user's speed for slow movements (Cordova library, phone)

Tags: javascript, cordova, gps, hybrid

I am trying to find a way to measure the user's speed that he/she is moving. I understand that you can use the GPS [Geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) to watch the position of the user's device at certain intervals:

```
t=0: (x0,y0)
t=1: (x1,y1)
```

where `x,y` are the GPS coordinates, and then simply apply pythagoras theorem to calculate the distance and use that to calculate the speed.

However, the GPS measurement might not be that accurate when the user is moving a slow speeds (for example running), because the **bias as a fraction of the total distance covered per interval** is larger due to the inaccuracy implied by the User's GPS sensor.

How can we then get a more accurate measure of the movements when moving at slow speeds?

Comment: _"the GPS might not be that accurate"_, based on speed? Speed has nothing to do with accuracy. The accuracy is influenced more by the device's reception.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes you are technically right. But I was assuming that if a device's reception is bad (and it says: location accurate up to 10 meters), that when you move at a higher speed, that bias is smaller (because you are covering larger distances after each interval, so the 10 meters are a smaller fraction of the total distance covered, than when moving at slow speed and covering less distance for each interval).